# Solving equations that involve derivatives, but not as differential equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have six equations from electromagnetism which are easy to solve for four of the variables, in terms of the remaining two. They happen to be differential equations, but I'm not interested in solving them *as differential equations*, I am just interested in a simple algebraic step. It is trivial to do by hand, but I can't figure out a nice way to trick mathematica into doing it! We go from these:

[image]

to these:

[image]

Does anyone know how to effect this transformation without clunky intermediate steps? Here are the equations:

```
equations={I*\[Omega]*Bx[x, y] - I*k*\[CapitalEpsilon]y[x, y] + 
   Derivative[0, 1][\[CapitalEpsilon]z][x, y] == 0, 
   \[Omega]*By[x, y] + k*\[CapitalEpsilon]x[x, y] + 
   I*Derivative[1, 0][\[CapitalEpsilon]z][x, y] == 0, 
 I*\[Omega]*Bz[x, y] + Derivative[1, 0][\[CapitalEpsilon]y][x, y] == 
     Derivative[0, 1][\[CapitalEpsilon]x][x, 
   y], (-I)*c*k*By[x, y] + (I*\[Omega]*\[CapitalEpsilon]x[x, y])/c + 
   c*Derivative[0, 1][Bz][x, y] == 0, 
   c*k*Bx[x, y] + (\[Omega]*\[CapitalEpsilon]y[x, y])/c + 
   I*c*Derivative[1, 0][Bz][x, y] == 0, 
   -((I*\[Omega]*\[CapitalEpsilon]z[x, y])/c) + 
   c*Derivative[0, 1][Bx][x, y] - c*Derivative[1, 0][By][x, y] == 0}
```

And this is the code that "should" work:

```
Solve[equations, {Bx[x, y], By[x, y], Ex[x, y], Ey[x, y]}]
```

Comment: Why don't you try `Solve[equations, {Bx[x, y], By[x, y], Bz[x, y], Ex[x, y], Ey[x, y], 
  Ez[x, y]}]`? (Or with the symbols you're actually using: `Solve[equations, {Bx[x, y], By[x, y], 
  Bz[x, y], \[CapitalEpsilon]x[x, y], \[CapitalEpsilon]y[x, 
   y], \[CapitalEpsilon]z[x, y]}]`). The point is, you have six equations, so tell Mathematica to solve for the six unknowns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

equations = {I*ω*Bx[x, y] - I*k*Εy[x, y] + 
     Derivative[0, 1][Εz][x, y] == 
    0, ω*By[x, y] + k*Εx[x, y] + 
     I*Derivative[1, 0][Εz][x, y] == 0, 
   I*ω*Bz[x, y] + Derivative[1, 0][Εy][x, y] == 
    Derivative[0, 1][Εx][x, 
     y], (-I)*c*k*By[x, y] + (I*ω*Εx[x, y])/c + 
     c*Derivative[0, 1][Bz][x, y] == 0, 
   c*k*Bx[x, y] + (ω*Εy[x, y])/c + 
     I*c*Derivative[1, 0][Bz][x, y] == 
    0, -((I*ω*Εz[x, y])/c) + 
     c*Derivative[0, 1][Bx][x, y] - c*Derivative[1, 0][By][x, y] == 0};
```

Either, use the option [`MaxExtraConditions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxExtraConditions.html)

```
Solve[equations, {Bx[x, y], 
  By[x, y], Εx[x, y], Εy[x, y]}, 
 MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

[image]

Or specify elimination variables in addition to solve variables

```
Solve[equations, {Bx[x, y], 
  By[x, y], Εx[x, y], Εy[x, y]}, {Bz[x, 
   y], Εz[x, y]}]
```

[image]

Or as suggested by march solve for as many variables as there are equations.

```
Solve[equations, {Bx[x, y], By[x, y], 
  Bz[x, y], Εx[x, y], Εy[x, 
   y], Εz[x, y]}]
```

[image]